# How to implement GLSurfaceView.IRenderer in Mono for Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, xamarin

I'm reading the android OpenGL ES tutorial and I got the the point where I have to implement my renderer ([link to the tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html#renderer)).

I'm trying to replicate this in Mono for Android, so I'm assuming that the interface I have to implement is `GLSurfaceView.IRenderer`, but this interface implements `Android.Runtime.IJavaObject`, which requires `IntPtr Handle { get; }`.

The tutorial doesn't mention this, because this problem obviously doesn't exist in java.

How can I implement this property? Or is there a more straightforward way of working with OpenGL ES in Mono for Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class should inherit from [`Java.Lang.Object`](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3aJava.Lang.Object), which will implement `IJavaObject` for you properly.